# Count value Sate not getting updating - React JS

Tags: reactjs

When load more is clicked, `count` value is not getting updated only on the second click it is getting updated.

Expectation is on load more button click value should be passed as `2`, but now it is sending as `1`.

what I'm doing wrong here. Please guide

Below is the sample code.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

fetchData() {
.....
}

loadMore() {
 ....
 fetchData()
}
```

Render HTML Method:

```
<button onClick={ () => {
setCount(count + 1);
loadMore();
}}
```

Comment: Where you are passing the state value? Where do you log it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this -

```
const handleOnClick = () => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
    loadMore();
}}

<button onClick={handleOnClick}>Click me</button>
```

Comment: still in request it is sending as 1

Comment: It should be working. You can debug by declaring one another state as a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the answer here in this react documentation.

[I’ve updated the state, but logging gives me the old value.](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/usestate#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value)